# usage of #define to print values

Tags: c

I have seen code where #define is used like following. The code is used to print values of different stages. Is there any document where I could read about similar #define concept?

```
#define $STAGES$ "{"    \
    "0=Stage1,"      \
    "1=Stage2,"     \
    "2=Stage3,"      \
    "?=?" "}"
```

Comment: That's just a `#define` that resolves into a string literal; what are you looking for?

Comment: There's nothing magic about that `define`, it's just a string literal.

Comment: Well, there _is_ something magic... gcc allows `$STAGES$` to be a macro name, but normally that's not allowed.

Comment: Dollar signs are allowed in identifiers by *lots* of compilers.

Comment: Just consider #define to be coding variables.  They are used to make code more readable/maintainable.  It does nothing but replace the name with the code.

Comment: I have always used #define like #define STAGE1 1 , I do not understand why "$" is placed before and after STAGES "$STAGES"

Comment: The dollar signs are, according to @CarlNorum (and I'll defect to his judgment), just part of the token name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that is doing is setting `$STAGES$` to a literal string:

```
"{0=Stage1,1=Stage2,2=Stage3,?=?}"
```

(It doesn't print anything.)

When you type literal strings next to each other, they are automatically concatenated into a single literal string. The `\` backslashes at the end of the lines combine them together.

Comment: Dollar sounds are allowed in identifiers by *lots* of compilers.

Comment: @CarlNorum: As an extension yes.  C and C++ disallow it technically, but many (all?) compilers allow it.

Comment: so is $ sign part of the syntax? will "#define STAGES " will also work instead of "#define $STAGES$"

Comment: @MooingDuck Since he didn't write it, I'll just assume it compiles, despite not being pedantic.

Comment: @user968000 It will define alright...but any code using the name will probably need to have it changed to `STAGES` too.

Comment: How can we use this code to print the values of stages? if the value is 0, stage1 should be printed , if the value is 1 , stage2 should be printed.

Comment: @user968000 I'd eschew this entirely then; use a map or array. But you asked what it did, not why it did so.

Comment: @chqrlie Ah, of course. The `"?=?" "}"` threw me off.

Comment: @user968000: these `$` signs are part of the identifier `$STAGES$`. They are not part of the grammar nor play any specific role.  Using `$` signs in identifiers is allowed by many compilers as an extension, such an extension is actually condoned by the C Standard (section *J.5.2 Specialized identifiers* in the latest C11 draft)